# How to setup stripe account with Indian bank account and can accept international payment?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am integrating stripe payment gateway for my project. My project provide digital goods to my customers. I have done some code like this :

[image]

1. I am passing currency `'inr'` and amount is received from product id from database. But my payment is failed if I use currency is `'usd'`.
2. It is showing me error like this :

[image]

Can anyone please guide me where I am wrong ?.

I have setup my stripe account as Indian business account. I want to accept international payment and follow [this doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-international-payments-from-stripe-accounts-in-india) for further research about business on stripe.

I also read about business that some transaction purpose code is required for accept payment. but where to put that code I can't find such setting in stripe dashboard.

Please help me. Any small help would be very helpful for me.

Comment: The guide for how you need to update your integration as an Indian merchant to accept international payments is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments).

Comment: Thank you so much For Reply Jonathan, Can I get some visual flow for this ?

Comment: There's no real difference to the flow you outlined. You just need to pass the additional parameters highlighted in the doc when creating the payment Intent.

Comment: Okay, Let me try that one.

Comment: Sorry brother, That is not working. I don't know where I am wrong. I have passed billling detail with buyer name in payment intent but still payment is failed.

Comment: You should write into Stripe for some additional [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact)!

Answer (score 1):

After lot's of research and help of stripe's suppport team, I found this solution.

I am sending this details while creating payment intent

```
//BE
const customer = stripe.customers.create({
    name : "customer name",
    address: {
        line1: '510 Townsend St',
        postal_code: '98140',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
     }
})

const paymentIntent = stripe.paymentIntents.create({
   amount: amount,
   currency: currency,
   description: "product description",
   customer: customr.id
})

// FE
stripe.confirmPaymentIntent(paymentIntent.client_secret, {
   options....
})
```

and then setup stripe account tax information on this link : https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/taxation
**NOTE :** business type individual can't accept international payment. So select other then individual.

after select business type. Just go to https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/update and then update export information and that's it. You can now accept international payment in USD.